# raphael.js how to add id to a path

Tags: javascript, path, svg, raphael

I just started using Raphael.js and I am stumped on adding an id to a path. I have read a lot of posts on how to do it, but I think the way my file is set up doesn't allow me to easily translate those solutions.

I have an init.js file and a path.js file

init.js

```
var r = Raphael('man', 500, 573),
    attributes = {
        fill: '#204ad3',
        opacity: '0.0',
        'stroke-linejoin': 'round'

    },
arr = new Array();

for (var muscles in paths) {

    var obj = r.path(paths[muscles].path);

    obj.attr(attributes);

    arr[obj.id] = muscles;

    obj
    .hover(function(){
        this.animate({
            fill: '#204ad3',
            opacity: '0.3'
        }, 300);
    }, function(){
        this.animate({
            fill: attributes.fill,
            opacity: attributes.opacity
        }, 300);
    })
    .click(function(){
        document.location.hash = arr[this.id];

        var point = this.getBBox(0);

        $('#man').next('.point').remove();

        $('#man').after($('<div />').addClass('point'));

        $('.point')
        .html(paths[arr[this.id]].name)
        .prepend($('<a />').attr('href', '#').addClass('close').text('Close'))
        .prepend($('<img />').attr('src', 'flags/'+arr[this.id]+'.png'))
        .css({
            left: point.x+(point.width/2)-80,
            top: point.y+(point.height/2)-20
        })
        .fadeIn();

    });

    $('.point').find('.close').live('click', function(){
        var t = $(this),
            parent = t.parent('.point');

        parent.fadeOut(function(){
            parent.remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

path.js file:

```
var paths = { 
    neck: {
        name: 'Neck',
    path: 'd="M412.294,73.035c0,0,7.661,28.869,9.406,31.78c1.746,2.911,4.657,2.911,9.896,2.911 s9.313-1.746,9.896-5.239c0.582-3.493,6.985-28.523,6.985-28.523s-2.963,2.599-6.232,5.984c-2.543,2.632-7.2,5.904-11.088,5.904 c-3.889,0-6.705-2.431-10.367-5.04C418.063,78.868,418.08,79.22,412.294,73.035z"',
},
pecks: {
    name: 'Pecks',
    path: 'd="M379.581,117.994c0,0,0.396-1.586,6.936-4.558c6.539-2.972,13.475-5.351,16.844-6.737 c3.369-1.387,4.559-1.784,4.559-1.784s13.674,2.973,15.061,3.17c1.387,0.198,4.36,1.982,8.72,1.982s9.511-1.387,11.097-2.18 s10.307-2.973,11.693-3.171s1.387-0.198,1.387-0.198s12.286,3.369,16.845,4.36c4.558,0.991,8.917,2.378,9.116,3.765 c0.197,1.387,1.584,4.954,1.584,6.341s-0.197,5.945-0.396,6.738c-0.198,0.792-3.171,15.457-4.757,21.997 c-1.585,6.54-1.188,8.918-7.331,11.494s-10.899,7.53-22.79,2.378s-13.277-5.549-17.241-5.152s-11.098,3.963-14.862,5.351 c-3.766,1.387-16.251,2.179-20.412-0.198c-4.162-2.378-10.9-9.314-12.881-16.844c-1.981-7.531-3.963-16.052-4.359-17.638 C377.995,125.525,377.798,121.165,379.581,117.994z"',
},
}
```

The generated SVG element does not have an id, nor do I know how to get one in there. Any advise/help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will add the `id` attribute to the svg path elements:

```
var id = 0;

for (var muscles in paths) {

    var obj = r.path(paths[muscles].path);
    obj.node.id = "muscles_or_whatever_you_want_" + id;
    id++

    //....
```

Comment: I want to add something to the click event that would show or hide divs based on each path. So the class would be .tag-(something) where (something) would change to the name of the path. Is that possible? Currently the popup uses the path name to add the muscle name. Wonder how I can use something similar to accomplish what I mentioned to this: `$('.tag-something').show();`

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying go do. I'd suggest to post another question. It's probably possible if you create class names the same way ids are created.

Comment: Thank you mihai. If you're interested I have asked this question in  [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454235/raphael-js-ie8-and-jquery)

Comment: By Default, Raphael doesn't allow class names on items; you have to override it with this line: `Raphael._availableAttrs["class"] = "";` Otherwise, any `class` attributes you specify will be ignored/removed.

Answer (score 1):

to add an id to a SVG element .... 
`paper.path( path data ).node.id = 'pathIdString';`. to test ... try `alert( document.getElementById("pathIdString").id );`. should return the id

Comment: this worked to me because it's easier to understand. now i can apply the css very well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to do is to pop up a div with an image and a close link above the path that is clicked. The problem is that you are confusing the Raphael id of the path object with the index in your `paths` array. You probably want to eliminate `arr` entirely and pass the index to your handler through a closure:

```
.click(function(index) { return function() {
    document.location.hash = index;

    var point = this.getBBox(0);

    $('#man').next('.point').remove();

    $('#man').after($('<div />').addClass('point'));

    $('.point')
    .html(paths[index].name)
    .prepend($('<a />').attr('href', '#').addClass('close').text('Close'))
    .prepend($('<img />').attr('src', 'flags/'+index+'.png'))
    .css({
        left: point.x+(point.width/2)-80,
        top: point.y+(point.height/2)-20
    })
    .fadeIn();

}; }(muscles));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will apply those adjustments and see what happens. I'm not sure if your solution adds an id within the path element. That would be important, not for the popup, but to control elements outside the svg.

Comment: I want to be able to control a group of dl elements that would hide and show depending on the muscle group that is clicked. I have set that part up before using SVG without Rafael. If I was able to assign an ID to a path with this setup, than I would be very happy. Is it possible?