# raphael.js IE8 and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-8, raphael

I am creating an anatomic man where the user can rollover muscles, the muscles are highlighted and when clicked they display the name of the muscle. Through a separate JQuery, I have a group of `<dl>`s that show and hide depending on the muscle group clicked. This works fine in IE9, and other modern browsers, but I am having an issue within IE8. IE8 only wants to use the code within the generated raphael.js. So I need to move the jquery into raphael…which I'm sure will be a more elegant way of doing this. However, I am unsure of how to proceed with this.

Here is my code:

paths.js

```
var paths = { 
neck: {
    name: 'neck',
    path: 'd="M412.294,73.035c0,0,7.661,28.869,9.406,31.78c1.746,2.911,4.657,2.911,9.896,2.911 s9.313-1.746,9.896-5.239c0.582-3.493,6.985-28.523,6.985-28.523s-2.963,2.599-6.232,5.984c-2.543,2.632-7.2,5.904-11.088,5.904 c-3.889,0-6.705-2.431-10.367-5.04C418.063,78.868,418.08,79.22,412.294,73.035z"',
},
pecks: {
    name: 'Pecks',
    path: 'd="M379.581,117.994c0,0,0.396-1.586,6.936-4.558c6.539-2.972,13.475-5.351,16.844-6.737 c3.369-1.387,4.559-1.784,4.559-1.784s13.674,2.973,15.061,3.17c1.387,0.198,4.36,1.982,8.72,1.982s9.511-1.387,11.097-2.18 s10.307-2.973,11.693-3.171s1.387-0.198,1.387-0.198s12.286,3.369,16.845,4.36c4.558,0.991,8.917,2.378,9.116,3.765 c0.197,1.387,1.584,4.954,1.584,6.341s-0.197,5.945-0.396,6.738c-0.198,0.792-3.171,15.457-4.757,21.997 c-1.585,6.54-1.188,8.918-7.331,11.494s-10.899,7.53-22.79,2.378s-13.277-5.549-17.241-5.152s-11.098,3.963-14.862,5.351 c-3.766,1.387-16.251,2.179-20.412-0.198c-4.162-2.378-10.9-9.314-12.881-16.844c-1.981-7.531-3.963-16.052-4.359-17.638 C377.995,125.525,377.798,121.165,379.581,117.994z"',
},
}
```

init.js

```
$(function(){

var r = Raphael('man', 500, 573),
    attributes = {
        fill: '#204ad3',
        opacity: '0.0',
        'stroke-linejoin': 'round'

    },
arr = new Array();

var id = 0;

for (var muscles in paths) {

    var obj = r.path(paths[muscles].path);

    obj.attr(attributes);

    obj.node.id = "muscle" + id;
    id++

    arr[obj.id] = muscles;

    obj
    .hover(function(){
        this.animate({
            fill: '#204ad3',
            opacity: '0.3'
        }, 300);
    }, function(){
        this.animate({
            fill: attributes.fill,
            opacity: attributes.opacity
        }, 300);
    })

    .click(function(){
        document.location.hash = arr[this.id];

        var point = this.getBBox(0);

        $('#man').next('.point').remove();

        $('#man').after($('<div />').addClass('point'));

        $('.point')
        .html(paths[arr[this.id]].name)
        .prepend($('<a />').attr('href', '#').addClass('close').text('Close'))
        .css({
            left: point.x+(point.width/2)-80,
            top: point.y+(point.height/2)-20
        })
        .fadeIn();

    });

    $('.point').find('.close').live('click', function(){
        var t = $(this),
            parent = t.parent('.point');

        parent.fadeOut(function(){
            parent.remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
}   

});
```

In the init.js code there is a `click(function()` that generates a popup for the muscle group. How could I add a code that would allow other jquery to happen depending on the path the user clicks? Something like:

```
$("dl").hide().delay(100);$('.tag-pathnamehere').show();
```

where 'pathnamehere' part of the class would change depending on the path clicked.

I believe this line adds the path name to the popup:

```
(paths[arr[this.id]].name)
```

I would like to somehow change the 'pathnamehere' part of the class to the path clicked.

I hope this is clear and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what the element selected with `$('.tag-pathnamehere')` is. Does this refer to the path itself or some other html element? Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/ZZp25/4/) of your code

Comment: `$('tag-pathnamehere')` would refer to some other element. There will be several `dl`s with class of .tag-neck or .tag-chest that I would want to show or hide depending on the path that is clicked. Being able to change out just the 'pathnamehere' aspect would allow the 'tag-' part to remain and simply use the path name attribute, maybe.

Comment: why not use HTML5's `data-` custom attributes instead of abusing the `classname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `dl` elements are already created (are they?), I guess you could do something like:

```
arr = new Array();
tags = new Array();

...
arr[obj.id] = muscles;

tags[obj.id] = ".tag-" + paths[muscles].name;
```

and then in the `click` handler

```
$(tags[this.id]).show();
```

Comment: I do have dl elements already created. Your solution seems promising, but I cannot get it to work. Is there a way to check how the variable is showing up when the path is clicked?

Comment: yea, if you know how to use firebug or chrome inspector you can put a breakpoint in the click handler

Comment: Thanks for that. I have a lot to learn. Interestingly enough, I learned that `var tagname = ".tag-" + paths[muscles].name;` references the last path name in paths.js and not the path that is being clicked. Any idea as to why?

Comment: ah, yes, my bad...didn't see this coming. The tagname is redeclared at every iteration. You can store it in another array, or simply in the obj. Updating answer

Comment: That works! Thank you. I appreciate your time and efforts in showing me the answer. I really like that inspector…which helped a lot.